# Program to transform text into lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to write program which returns text ordered in lists.

text file example:

```
sayndz zfxlkl attjtww cti sokkmty brx fhh suelqbp
xmuf znkhaes pggrlp zia znkhaes znkhaes
nti rxr bogebb zdwrin
sryookh unrudn zrkz jxhrdo gctlyz
```

My idea is to divide text to list elements where each line is one list element and next again I try to divide each line to list where each word is list elements. In mostly works but in the end I get back only first line of text changed into list.

This is what I get back:
['sayndz', 'zfxlkl', 'attjtww', 'cti', 'sokkmty', 'brx', 'fhh', 'suelqbp']

And this is my code:

```
class SkyphrasesValidation(object):

    def get_text_file(self):
        file = open('C:/Users/PC/Documents/skychallenge_skyphrase_input.txt', 'r')
        return file

    def lines_list(self):
        text = self.get_text_file()
        lines_list = text.readlines()
        return lines_list

    def skyphrase_list(self):
        for line in self.lines_list():
            words_list = line.split()
            return words_list

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.skyphrase_list())

text = SkyphrasesValidation()

print(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular problem, I think the issue lies with the return statement inside skyphrase_list(). specifically:

```py
    def skyphrase_list(self):
        for line in self.lines_list():
            words_list = line.split()
            return words_list
```

What happens in this line is that it starts the loop, and then after splitting the line, returns back the first result -- it doesn't actually iterate through the entire list.

So, this should solve the problem, but there's a different way I'll show after this:

```py
    def skyphrase_list(self):
        rtn = []  # create a list to hold the loop processing
        for line in self.lines_list():
            words_list = line.split()
            rtn.append(words_list)  # tack on the parsed line to the return object
        return rtn  # do the return outside of the loop
```

But the way you've done this is a bit strange to me. Here's how I'd solve this problem:

```py
def read_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as fh:
        return fh.read()  # to make sure you properly close the file. You can do more processing here as well if you're so inclined.

def to_word_list(body):
    lines = body.split()  # the initial split, as you have it
    return [line.split() for line in lines]  # a split on each level, represented as a list comprehension
```

This route is a lot less code, and isn't tied to a class, but your needs may be different.

Answer (score 1):

In `skyphrase_list`, you need to construct a list like so:

```
def skyphrase_list(self):
    words_list = []
    for line in self.lines_list():
        words_list.append(line.split())
    return words_list
```

However, there is a better way of going about all of this. I will let you adapt it into a class, but in bare code, it looks like:

```
with open('C:/Users/PC/Documents/skychallenge_skyphrase_input.txt', 'r') as infile:
    words_list = [line.split() for line in infile]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `skyphrase_list`, you need to append your individual list of words to a bigger list, you should also ignore empty lines, This gives you a list of lists, with each list corresponding to a line

```
def skyphrase_list(self):
    bigger_list = []
    for line in self.lines_list():
        if line:
            bigger_list.append(line.split())
    return bigger_list
```

Then an expected output might look like below, not sure if that is what you are looking for.

```
[['sayndz', 'zfxlkl', 'attjtww', 'cti', 'sokkmty', 'brx', 'fhh', 'suelqbp'],  
 ['xmuf', 'znkhaes', 'pggrlp', 'zia', 'znkhaes', 'znkhaes'], 
 ['nti', 'rxr', 'bogebb', 'zdwrin'], 
 ['sryookh', 'unrudn', 'zrkz', 'jxhrdo', 'gctlyz']]
```